# UITableViewCell blinks when the height changes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I use Auto `Layout` cells with automatic `height` calculation. When I change one of the cell height constraint, call `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` for the `UITableView`, everything is rebuilt correctly, but the animation does not work the way I want — I would like the height of the cell to simply increase, without blinking and moving its upper part. What may it depend on?

I am attaching the GIF with how it is wrong for me to animate now.
https://vk.com/doc19187792_491076127

Comment: Can you your animation code.

Comment: I have no animation code, I just change the value of the constraint, and then I call beginUpdates() and endUpdates().

Comment: Where is the expanded view. Its just showing uncollapsed state with large height. And which constraint you are increasing? Please update the question with Expanded image and Collapsed state.

Answer (score 0):

You can write extension to your Cell class and add some animation, and add your cell whenever hit.. Also you should write a completion block to this, when your animation finished, height for row at is called.

This is not your complete solution but you can edit so that your problem may be solved.

```
extension UIView {

func glow(_ completion: @escaping () -> ()){

    let opacity = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    let pulse = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    let group = CAAnimationGroup()

    pulse.fromValue = 0.4
    pulse.toValue = 1

    opacity.fromValue = 0
    opacity.toValue = 0.65

    group.animations = [pulse, opacity]
    group.duration = 1.1
    group.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeOut)
    group.autoreverses = false
    group.repeatCount = 0

    layer.add(group, forKey: nil)

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+1) {
        completion()
    }
}
}
```